# Device gallery images are not showing in device for ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, alassetslibrary

I'm implemented the **ALAsset** library for getting the device or local gallery images to my application.Its working in iOS 6 device.But if i'm trying to run the same app in iOS 7 the gallery images are not display.
Please anybody suggest me how to resolve this.
Sorry for the poor English.

Comment: Maybe you should add some of your code to see if there´s something that won't make it work on iOS 7.

Comment: try to delete the app and reinstall the app . At the very first time you will get one alert like do you want to access the saved photos . It is a default alert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code it works perfectly in all iOS versions

```
//Method to get all images from devices library
 - (NSMutableArray*)getAllImagesFromLibrary
 {
     //get all images from image library

     void (^assetEnumerator)(ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
         if(result != NULL) {
             if ([[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] isEqualToString:ALAssetTypePhoto])
             {
                 //Insert objects into array
                 [self.arrOfAllImages addObject:result];
             }
         }
     };

     void (^assetGroupEnumerator)(ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) =  ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
     if(group != nil) {
         [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetEnumerator];
        }
     };

     //NSMutableArray allacation
     NSMutableArray *arrOfAllImage = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;
     static ALAssetsLibrary *library = nil;
     dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
         library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
     });

     [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos
     usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
     failureBlock: ^(NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"Failure");
     }];

     return arrOfAllImage;

}
```

Comment: Thank you Arpit.But I'm also done the same way.But No use.

Comment: Its working fine in my app for all versions.called it like - (void)getImages {
    self.arrOfAllImages = [self getAllImagesFromLibrary];
} and call [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.001 target:self selector:@selector(getImages) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
in viewDidAppear.

Comment: I think need to change device settings option.For syncing the gallery images.But I'm not getting the option like sync.

Comment: Is there any other way to get those photos or imamgs?

Comment: NSLog the ALAsset *result before add to the array. And is it working on simulator or not?

Comment: working in simulator.But in device not showing the images.In NSLOG also print the image names.

Comment: Thank you Arpit for your suggestions.Its working now.I get the problem and resolved in my app.the condition is wrong in my side.Thanks again.